# For each row, add column name to list in new column if row value matches a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a series of columns, each containing either `Y` or `N`.

I would like to create a new column that contains a list of columns (for that particular row) that contain `Y`.

**Old DataFrame**

```
>>> df

     col1        col2        col3         col4        col5
a    Y           N           N            N           Y
b    Y           N           Y            Y           Y
c    N           N           Y            N           N
```

**New Dataframe**

```
>>> df_new

     col1        col2        col3         col4        col5     col6
a    Y           N           N            N           Y        [col1, col5]
b    Y           N           Y            Y           Y        [col1, col3, col4, col5]
c    N           N           Y            N           N        [col3]
```

So far I can get it working for a single column with:

```
df["col6"] = ["col1" if val == "Y" else "" for val in df["col1"]]
```

But ideally I want to do the same for all columns, so I somehow end up with the result above. I could imagine doing some kind of loop, but then how I go about appending the result to the list value in `col6` I'm unsure on. Can someone steer me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare values by `Y` first, then use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df["col6"] = df.eq('Y').dot(df.columns + ',').str[:-1].str.split(',')
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5                      col6
a    Y    N    N    N    Y              [col1, col5]
b    Y    N    Y    Y    Y  [col1, col3, col4, col5]
c    N    N    Y    N    N                    [col3]
```

Or if need better performance use list comprehension with numpy arrays:

```
cols = df.columns.to_numpy()
df["col6"] = [cols[x].tolist() for x in df.eq('Y').to_numpy()]
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you. Also, I'm just wondering how you practiced Pandas? Did you do a course, or just experience? I struggle a bit with this kind of stuff

Comment: @AaronWright - For me working many, many hours of coding

Comment: Well thank you for this. It works! I'll need to start practicing Pandas more

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you're able to, but can you explain how `.dot` is working in this? From what I can tell, this is just for matrix multiplication?

Comment: @AaronWright - yes, exatly. Boolean DataFrame working like `0, 1` for `False, True`s, so if use dot with columns names get joined values in column by separator, here `,`

Comment: @AaronWright - yes, exatly. Boolean DataFrame working like `0, 1` for `False, True`s, so if use dot with columns names get joined values in column by separator, here `,`